# How can I override bootstrap parent class .text-md-left only to <a> tags

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want these two `<a>` tags at the end to be centered, but declaring the class .text-center directly on the tag isn't working.
How can I force then to be centered without using !important?

```
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4 text-center text-md-left">
          
    <p class="display-4 font-weight-bold pt-4">
      Lorem ipsum.
    </p>
    
    <hr class="hr-light">
    
    <a target="_blank" href="#" class="btn btn-indigo btn-lg text-center">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg text-center">Lorem ipsum</a>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just had a couple of classes in your parent that were the issue. Removing them centered the buttons for you

```
<div class="mb-4 text-center ">
```

Hopefully this fixes this for you..
https://jsfiddle.net/z30bp7th/

#########

Hi,

To center the anchors only I would wrap them in container and center its conents.

I've updated this fiddle to center ONLY the buttons. Hope it helps !
https://jsfiddle.net/8fkz7xoq/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this centers all the tags.  Is there a way to keep the class text-md-left to all children tags, except for tag a